# List of Azure Continous WebJob's functions programatically

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-webjobssdk

I want to list down the functions of an Azure Continous WebJobs using C# code. Is it possible to achieve this using Kudu's API? Or is there any other alternatives to get this list?

Comment: [this](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) is the api description, it mentions nothing about what you are trying to achieve, but it might be i'm not looking hard enough

Comment: I have updated my question: i am looking for API that can return the list of functions contained inside continuous type webjobs.

Comment: I am still not able to find any references to achieve this. I have continous webjobs and i want to list down the functions inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [KUDU API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk84V.png) to list all of your trigger webjobs. 
Using `GET /api/continuouswebjobs`.

Refer to the following code:

```
string userName = "$";

string userPassword = "";

string webAppName = "";

var base64Auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes($"{userName}:{userPassword}"));

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Auth);
    var baseUrl = new Uri($"https://{webAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/");
    var requestURl = baseUrl + "api/continuouswebjobs";
    var response = client.GetAsync(requestURl).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var json = JArray.Parse(response?.Result);
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < json.Count; i++)
    {
        var name = json[i]["name"];
        list.Add(name.ToString());
    }
}
```

The WebJob API requires [**Basic Authentication**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/02/01/using-the-azure-webjob-api/) using the publishing credentials, the different type of credentials are discussed [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials).  You can download your publishing credentials from the Azure portal in `Get Publish Profile`.

The output is as below:
[image]

Comment: This will return the webjobs with triggered type only, not the continuous webjob's functions. I am referring functions inside continous webjobs. I have updated my question. However i already up-voted your answer as my mistake for giving unclear question

Comment: That's the same. You only have to change `requestURl = baseUrl + "/api/continuouswebjobs"`. And it will show you [all continuous webjobs](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#list-all-continuous-jobs).

Comment: I am only getting following response:     {
        "status": "Running",
        "detailed_status": "- Running\r\n",
        "log_url": "https://***.scm.azurewebsites.net/vfs/data/jobs/continuous/***/job_log.txt",
        "name": "***Jobs",
        "run_command": "***.exe",
        "url": "https://***.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/continuouswebjobs/***",
        "extra_info_url": "https://***.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/#/jobs/continuous/***",
        "type": "continuous",
        "error": null,
        "using_sdk": true,
        "settings": {}
    },

Comment: @h2chch, I have update my reply you could refer to. I get the webjob name using JArray to analyze the response. Hope this could help you.

Comment: The thing is contained functions are not listed under the response. I don't think there's API to achieve my objective

Comment: It seems that there is no way to achieve that. Sorry for my misunderstanding.